# Django DeleteView doesn't redirect to success url after overriding delete method

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I have a student model which includes a foreign key of django user model, I want to delete the associated user when student is removed (on `delete=CASCADE` does vice versa), so I override the delete method but after deletion `success_url= '/student/'` is not working and url still is e.g. `'/students/delete/323/'` and keeps sending the pk to url, when I don't override delete method it works like a charm. any idea?

```
class StudentDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Student
    template_name_suffix = '_confirm_delete'
    success_url = '/students/'

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        related_user = Student.objects.get(student_id=kwargs['pk']).user_id
        User.objects.filter(id=related_user).delete()
        return super(StudentDeleteView, self).delete(request, *args, **kwargs)


class Student(models.Model):
    student_id = models.IntegerField()
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='students')
    courses = models.ManyToManyField('Course', through='StudentCourse', related_name='students')
    classrooms = models.ManyToManyField('Classroom', through='Register', related_name='students')
    last_modified_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    birth_date = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image', blank=True)
```

Comment: I can't see why that `delete` view would stop the redirection from working. Perhaps there is something else from your actual view that you are not including in your question.

Comment: thanks for your reply Alasdair, the point is it is only happening when I add delete function to override it, when  It's removed it works fine and redirection is ok, that's why I am suspicious about it, and if you think the problem is hiding somewhere else could you provide me more information to detect it

Comment: actually Page not found (404) happens and it's obvious because i don't have a deletion page for each user

Comment: Please show your `Student` model. Perhaps it should be `Student.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk']).user_id`.

Comment: question is edited and student model is added

Comment: The `student_id` is not the primary key, so it looks like it should be `Student.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk']).user_id`.

Comment: Dear Alasdair, thanks a lot for your help but the issue wasn't about the primary key or stuff like that, in fact student id is sth that I've defined by myself. thanks to my friend i found the problem and it was due to manually handling user deletion, because of that, the object sent to ''super'' wasn't the same, and by overriding the whole delete method and not calling the super, problem goes away